# Siunitx conflicts with textbf

Tags: siunitx, bold

I've recently updated my computer from TeXLive 2019 to TeXLive 2022, and a document that compiled perfectly with the 2019 version raises an error with the new version. The problem occurs when i try to use the `\ohm` unit (defined in the `siunutx` package) inside a `\textbf` command, but the strange thing is that using the `\farad` unit the problem does not arise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$ \si{\textbf{\farad}} = \si{\coulomb \per \volt} $ → no problem

$ \si{\textbf{\ohm}} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} $ → raise an error

$ \si{\ohm} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} $ → no problem
\end{document}
```

I'm using the `$ ... $` because in other parts of the document I have to make some operations with these units, and also because this ensures the correct spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\mathbf` not `\textbf`, since `\Omega` is not "text".  An error would likewise occur if you had merely typed `$\textbf{\Omega}$`, in the absence of `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
$ \si{\textbf{\farad}} = \si{\coulomb \per \volt} $ → no problem

$ \si{\mathbf{\ohm}} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} $ → raise an error

$ \si{\ohm} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} $ → no problem
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So if I understanded correctly, siunitx has the macro `\ohm` but, behind the scenes, it only adds an `$\Omega$` and this requires a `\mathbf{}` command because `\Omega` is a math macro. Instead `\farad` just puts a normal `F` and this not strictly requires a `\mathbf{}` command.

Comment: Yes, @andreagoo8, this is a valid interpretation.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed one little detail: in the MWE that I posted wasn't clear, but I'm using the sans-serif family of latin modern via this line in the preamble: `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`. Using `\mathbf{}`, as you suggested, the the Ω in the pdf is serif. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @andreagoo8 One can use `\mathsf{ }` to get math in sans-serif.  However, unless the font is so equipped, you won't be able to get both bold and sans-serif simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be the following, for the case where you are writing plain text and need to accompany quantities with their respective units, in text mode it simply works with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\si{\textbf{\farad}} = \si{\coulomb \per \volt}  
\si{\textbf{\ohm}} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} 
\si{\ohm} = \si{\volt \per \ampere} 
\end{document}
```